# AngularStrap popover flickers for some reason

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

[image]

My HTML is:

```
            <div class="pull-left" data-trigger="hover" bs-popover="popover">
              <a href="/address/text">
                text
              </a>
            </div>
```

My controller has:

```
$scope.popover = {
  "title": "Title",
  "content": "Hello Popover<br />This is a multiline message!"
};
```

How come the popover doesn't always pop up? You don't see it in this GIF, but for a fraction of a second, the popover appears on the left before flickering in on the right. Also, why is the popover highlighted?

Comment: Can you make a plunker?

Comment: @shamoon The question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: It's probably happening due to some css in your classes. It would be great if you share the css involved with us...

Comment: I have no CSS additional. It's just bootstrap

Comment: @Shamoon No one can answer your question with what you've provided. We don't even know what versions you're using for each vendor library. There's obviously a lot more going on in the image than in your html snippet that could be causing all kinds of problems. There's weird hover behavior going on already, who knows that that is.. Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vLYv3irrdKYntHmmDOi?p=preview) with the information you've provided (using the newest libraries). If you add the rest of your html/css/js to the plnkr someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up a fiddle to show that you can just use inbuilt AngularJS directives to do this, including `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. There is no flickering from what I can see, either.

http://jsfiddle.net/jakemulley/dZe55/

Hopefully this helps!